# information regarding numerics of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, computational-mathematics, simulation, finite-difference-methods, finite-volume-method

I am learning conservation laws at the moment and now I have to start numerical solutions of the pde. I have to do finite volume schemes, it is advisable to go through finite difference first and then read finite volume?

and I want to learn the simulation on c++ for the same, can someone refer me a book or video lectures to learn the coding in c++ for numerical pde.

Comment: If you don't know finite differencing, then start with that. And start with finite differencing on ODEs, starting with PDEs would be nigh on impossible.

Comment: that's quite an information.